# If you don't speak your native language (e.g. Spanish) can you lose your native accent?

Tags: multiple-languages, native-language, accent

I am practising several foreign languages, i.e. Japanese, Korean, Standard Chinese and Russian (I am A1  in the first three) and my question is what will happen if I don't speak my native language (Spanish) a lot? Is it possible that I lose my native accent?

I just speak Spanish at home because my family don't speak any other languages, only Spanish. I listen a lot to Spanish in the street but I don't speak it a lot. I love Spanish but I would like learn other languages

Comment: I have a friend from Albania who, after living in the US for 15 years without speaking Albanian, finally went back to visit, and his friends made fun of him for losing his native accent. So, yes, your native language can deteriorate.

Comment: just deteriorate¿?